# expanding mean on rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, mean

I am trying to calculate expanding mean on rows in my dataframe using pandas.
All seems to be working fine if calculating for columns:

```
>>> t = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,np.nan])

>>> t
     0
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  4.0
4  5.0
5  NaN

>>> t.expanding(min_periods=2, axis=0).mean()
     0
0  NaN
1  1.5
2  2.0
3  2.5
4  3.0
5  3.0
```

however if I try the same rows, I get wrong results (seems like window of size 2 is applied all the time):

```
>>> t.T
     0    1    2    3    4   5
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0 NaN

>>> t.T.expanding(min_periods=2, axis=1).mean()
    0    1    2    3    4   5
0 NaN  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5 NaN
```

seems like bug to me, but maybe I'm missing something... any clues please?

Comment: Yes it seems like it is calculating the rolling mean instead. There are several [issues](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13753) regarding `axis=1` in GitHub and as far as I can tell it is not fixed yet.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me too, but if you want to get the "desired output" with a workaround this works `t.T.T.expanding(min_periods=2, axis=0).mean().T` ... p.s. Not sure if you really care about the output, it's more like you're seeking an answer about this bug (same here).

Comment: @Masoud thanks. it is clear that I can get the right result by transposing, I just wanted to be sure, that I'm not missing something...

Comment: @kekert sure. Let us know if you found anything about the bug/fix. Cheers.

Comment: @M-- Using pandas 0.25.1, I cannot reproduce the error. Maybe the bug was fixed with https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/whatsnew/v0.25.1.html or  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/whatsnew/v0.21.1.html#bug-fixes

Comment: @Qaswed right. If you follow the git hub issues addressed in the answer, you'll see that it's been resolved (at least for this specific example). Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a bug, listed on [github-pandas-expanding](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13753) and [github-pandas-rolling](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13503).

Comment: If you had the chance, when the issue was resolved, please report back and edit the answer. Thanks.